# How do you find the runtime of loops that affect eachother?

Tags: runtime, analysis, big-o

I am not sure the technical term for these kinds of loops (if one even exists), so I will provide an example:

```
x=0
i = 1
while(i<n)
    for(j=1 to n/i)
        x = x + (i-j)
    i*=2
return(x)
```

In this example, the while loop is directly changing the number of times the for loop runs, which is throwing me off for some reason

Normally, I would go line by line and see how many times each line would run, but because the number of times changes, I tried doing a summation but got a little lost... What would be a step by step way to solve this type of problem?

The answer in the notes is O(n), but when I did this I got nlog(n)

Any help is appreciated, this is review for my final

Also, if you know of any good places to find practice problems of this sort, I would appreciate it!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the analysis to this code is very similar to the one in this [lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-4-heaps-and-heap-sort) to find the running time of the procedure of building a max heap. the straightforward analysis of it resulted in nlgn complexity but when analysed using summations it turned out to be n just like your problem.

So back to your question, the outer loop runs [image]
 times  and the inner runs n / i. But since i grows exponentially, we can use another variable j that that is increased once at a loop iteration so it can be used in summation and change the bounds according to the relation [image].

The summation is
[image]
The sum is a geometric sequence whose result is [image]
so when n tends to infinity, it converges to a constant (2). Hence the summation is considered a constant factor and doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity of the code which is only O(n).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! so just to clarify, because i increases exponentially (specifically by a multiple of 2, so 2^j where j is the number of iterations), the while loops runs lgn times. Because the inner loop is essentially a summation of n/2^j, it becomes a geometric series which converges to a constant times n, leaving the O(n)?

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense, thank you! I didnt consider setting i to 2^j, so I was getting lost